# MySQL does not update correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to have a little trouble with some basic mysql commands. This is the table called item that I created:

```
mysql> describe item;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| item_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| item_name  | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| item_price | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and this is the line of code i'm using to update this table:

```
$db = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'mac');
mysql_select_db('spending') or die(mysql_error($db));

$query = 'UPDATE item SET item_name = "' . $_POST['item_name'] . '",
                item_price = ' . $_POST['item_price'] . '  
                WHERE item_id = ' . $_GET['id'] . '';

$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
```

but every time I run it, it always complains like this:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE item_id = 1' at line 4
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this thing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Risk SQL Injection ...

Comment: replace mysql with mysqli

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not [parameterized your query to prevent MySQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).  Therefore, the $_POST and $_GET variables can contain anything, including malicious code.

In this case, you're lucky.  One of the variables is probably causing a syntax error.  A hacker could easily manipulate any of your variables to `DROP` you entire table, or read sensitive data from other tables.

In addition, php's original MySQL extension is now deprecated.  Make sure you use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL instead of php's MySQL extension.

Answer (score 0):

**Stop using mysql functions, they are deprecated**

Now that we got that out of the way:

```
//Connect to db
$db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'mac','spending');
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error;
}

//Prepare our query
$query = $db->prepare('UPDATE item SET item_name = ?,
                item_price = ?  
                WHERE item_id = ?');

//Bind the parameters
$item_name = (string)$_POST['item_name'];
$item_price = (int)$_POST['item_price'];
$item_id = (int)$_POST['id'];

$query->bind_param('sii',$item_name,$item_price,$item_id);

//Execute
$query->execute();
```

Read more about mysqli: http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Comment: yeah i tried it this is what it says:

Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /Library/WebServer/Documents/doc/dailyexpense/edit.php on line 37

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
 $query = 'UPDATE item SET `item_name` = "' . $_POST['item_name'] . '",
                    `item_price` = ' . $_POST['item_price'] . '  
                    WHERE `item_id` = '.$_GET['id'];
```